# How create a new line with table.create

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bdd, create-table

I have one problem with RubyonRails.
I created a BDD with a table Article.
For add some line on this table, I do :

```
hello = Article.new(:title => title, :content => content)
hello.save
```

But I know another method exists with "table.create title: 'title'"
But it didn't work with more than one column.
Can someone tell me how I can do thing like :

```
article.create = title: 'title', content: 'content'
```

Comment: `Article.create(title: "Title", content: "Content")` should work. Do you get an error when you try to use it?

Comment: yeah I have : [code]NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for #<Article:0x00557bb7ad3ee0>[code]
When I do : hello = Article.new
hello.create (title: 'title', content: 'content')

Comment: Are you typing `Article.create`? That error indicates that you are calling `.create` on an *instance* of `Article`, not the class itself

Comment: Oh god, you saved my life.. No i didnt try Article.create u_____u
Thank you man, all is good now !! :D